# How to get logged in user name?

Tags: c#

I want to take the current logged in user name (windows user) using c#, i have done the following.

1. Create one web application
2. Published the web application
3. Created the site in iis and given the physical path

when i try to get the user name , am getting the application pool name as current user name, i have used the below line of code. and i have given the anonymous access for this site.

```
string username = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
```

Comment: are you using asp.net membership?

Comment: Have you tried ,`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET? MVC? Forms Authentication? SimpleMembership?

Comment: I have tried WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; it gives like IIS APPOOL\my website name. At the same time when i run the appliaction from my local, am getting the correct windows logged used id, but when i publish the page to the server and try to access the page am gettng the IIS APPOOL \ Site Name

Comment: @@Trickery : am using ASP.Net, its a simple page, i just wanted to display the current logged in user name

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

If you are using membership then,

```
 MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
 //Get Username of Currently logged in user
 string username = currentUser.UserName;
 //Get UserId of Currently logged in user
 string UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-can-we-get-username-and-userid-of.html